# Inserting a dash based on certain criteria in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Hope someone can help with this.

I've got a column in Power BI that has aircraft registrations but they are without the required dash separator as shown the screenshot

[Power BI aircraft registration column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKVPB.png)

What I would like to be able to do is create another column and have some way of adding the dash in but based on certain criteria depending on the registration. E.g.

If Regno starts with OOxxx then OO-xxx

If Regno starts with Dxxxx then D-xxxx

If Regno start with YUxxx then YU-xxx

and so on..

Tried conditional columns but that doesn't work. Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: In the report edit page, you can right click the table and select "New Column" and then just do a SWITCH or IF statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a custom column with a formula like this:

```
if List.Contains({"OO","YU"},Text.Start([REGNO],2)) 
then Text.Start([REGNO],2) & "-" & Text.Middle([REGNO],2) 
else if List.Contains({"D"},Text.Start([REGNO],1)) 
then Text.Start([REGNO],1) & "-" & Text.Middle([REGNO],1) 
else [REGNO]
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what i was after!